# Spring Boot Application - Is it considered bad practice to throw EntityExists - or EntityNotFoundException from Service to Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jersey, jax-rs

My understanding of these exceptions is if an object in the database that you are looking for doesn't exist or exists these gets thrown? But is it ok for myself to use when I want to handle different cases in MyServiceClass.

Is it bad practice to throw these exceptions or should I create my own Exceptions for let's say if a user dont exist in the database?

How does it work in a real production?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should only implement a custom exception if it provides a benefit compared to Java's standard exceptions. The class name of your exception should end with Exception.
But it’s sometimes better to catch a standard exception and to wrap it into a custom one. A typical example for such an exception is an application or framework specific business exception. That allows you to add additional information and you can also implement a special handling for your exception class.

When you do that, make sure to set the original exception as the cause. The Exception class provides specific constructor methods that accept a Throwable as a parameter. Otherwise, you lose the stack trace and message of the original exception which will make it difficult to analyze the exceptional event that caused your exception.

```
public void wrapException(String input) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       throw new MyBusinessException("A message that describes the error.", e);
    }
}
```

Try not to create new custom exceptions if they do not have useful information for client code.
And if you make a custom exception be sure to:

1. Document the Exceptions You Specify
2. Throw Exceptions With Descriptive Messages
3. Catch the Most Specific Exception First
4. Don’t Log and Throw